# How can I append two array elements (int) into one array element (int)?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to take two elements of an array of integers, and append them, in order, into another array element, but only one.

Eg. int i[14] has all elements filled with numbers.

I want i[1] and i[2] stored into one element: temp[0].

Say i[1] = 123 and i[2] = 456, I want temp[0] = 123456.

I tried using strcat(), but it only works for type char.

Any suggestions?

**Edit** - I am working in C, not C++. Sorry.

Comment: `temp[0] = std::stoi(std::to_string(i[1]) + std::to_string(i[2]));` Basically, convert both to strings, concatenate the strings and then convert the concatenated string back to an integral type.

Comment: What about using sprintf(), then strcat() the two now-strings and converting back into an int?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your example: `temp[0] = i[1] * 1000 + i[2];`

In general you may want to work with any length of `i[2]`. So you will need to multiply by the right power of 10.

Here's one way to go about it:

```
int output = i[1];
for ( int x = i[2]; x; x /= 10 )
    output *= 10;
output += i[2];
```

When doing this, bear in mind that an `int` can only hold values up to `INT_MAX` (typically `2147483647`). If you overflow this then the behaviour is undefined. Consider using `unsigned long long` instead, and adding in overflow checks.

Comment: Thankyou, but I feel you deserve to hear the full story on what I need to do. I need to read in a binary file - no problem. It contains an integer, 4 bytes long. The next sequence of the file contains an unknown number of floating numbers, 8 bytes long each. I have read in the data, 4 bytes at a time, into an array. In doing so, I have accidentally 'split' each float in half. Now I'm trying to stitch the floats back together again. The ultimate goal is to display each number in order.

Comment: Well, that is completely and utterly different to your question. Post a new question that actually asks that!

Comment: Sorry! Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: OK. Also include in it the actual code that reads the data out of the file.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use string functions for this, you can do it with math, which is more efficient anyway:

```
temp[0] = pow(10, int(log10(i[2]))) * i[1] + i[2]
```

The idea is to figure out how many decimal places are in i[2] (3 if i[2] is 456), make 10 to that power to get 1000 which is the multiplication factor to then apply to i[1], so it comes out like this:

```
1000 * 123 + 456 == 123456
```